# Create an image map on a vehicle image

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate, mapping

I want to integrate a structure of vehicle image as follows for my website and on clicking on different spare parts I need to create different `<a>` tags. What is the best way to achieve this. I hear that image map need clear boundaries but in my case I think defining boundaries is much difficult. Say for an example we click on the 'break pads' then I need to browse the spares of break pads. What is the best way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[image: Say for an example this is the image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a very big work to do, but still I tried it with Front and Back disk pads.

```css
.image_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative
}
.image_wrapper > a.car_part {
    position: absolute;
}
a.car_part:hover {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
a.fdisk_break {
    top: 153px;
    width: 56px;
    height: 55px;
    left: 77px;
}
a.bdisk_break {
    top: 153px;
    width: 56px;
    height: 55px;
    right: 86px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEUvY.jpg">
  <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=front+disk+break" target="_blank" class="car_part fdisk_break" title="Front Disk break, click for search"></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=back+disk+break" target="_blank" class="car_part bdisk_break" title="Back Disk break, click for search"></a>
</div>
```

Try mouse-over on front or back break pad you will see popup with "Front Disk break" or "Back Disk break" respectively.

> It may not work because I'm using `px` which depends upon screen size